# Data structure like hashmap but with the ability to swap indexes in Java

Tags: java

I want to use a data structure to store column names of a JTable with their respective indexes, so that I can select the corresponding data column. If I filter out a column name, then the name and the index gets removed, if I put it back, the index will be the same. If I want to swap two columns, the indexes change but the column names stay the same. It also has to be serializable. Can I do this with a `HashMap<String,Integer>`?

I managed to load it with values, I basically filtered the dataList with the selected columnNames. I'm not too familiar with maps. As far as a know, I can't "swap" key's in HashMap

```java
private List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
private List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

public CustomTableModel(List<Object[]> dataList, Map<Integer,String> columnNames) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> set : columnNames.entrySet()) {
        this.columnNames.add(set.getValue());
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> selectedColIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> set : columnNames.entrySet()) { 
        selectedColIndexes.add(set.getKey());
    }

    for(int n=0; n<dataList.size(); n++) {
        Object[] selectedRow = new Object[columnNames.size()]; 
        for(int j=0; j<selectedColIndexes.size(); j++) {
            int index = selectedColIndexes.get(j);
            selectedRow[j]=dataList.get(n)[index];
        }

        data.add(selectedRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: short answer : you have a pair key-value so definitely you can do this with a `Map`. Now did you try something ?

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) will show you how you can link a DefaultTableModel with a JTable.

Comment: I'm unclear on what precisely is being asked.  I think showing what code has been attempted, and asking a specific question about that code, would help clarify matters.

Comment: Tried to add some details, hope I clarified it a bit.